# Apple JSON API not decoding properly in PHP

Tags: php, ios, json

I find out about Apple lookup API and wanted to try something.

JSON: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=443904275

It's only read resultCount, I can't read other data for example app name:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$json = file_get_contents('http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=443904275');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$appname = $data['artistName'];

echo "<pre>";
echo ($appname);

exit;
?>
```

Comment: so why don't you try some basic debugging, like `var_dump($data)` to see what you really got back from the api?

Comment: hi marc well i tried once but its dumping all, qestion is i cant fiqure it why cant read only one data

Comment: Paste your JSON data at http://json.parser.online.fr for better understanding of its structure. The `{}` brackets denote objects. The `[]` denote arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand the structure of the object. What you need is:

```
$appname = $data['results'][0]['artistName'];
```

Comment: its returing error in both changes   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Volumes/my1t/# SERVER/111/Untitled.php on line 9

Comment: jomathan its returing error on line 9 - $appname = $data['results'][1]['artistName'];  can you try it i use php 5.5.10 i dont know whats wrong

Comment: thank jonathan big kiss for you. :* :*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use $data['results'][0]['artistName']

...assuming $data['resultCount'] == 1.

You can always put http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=443904275 in your browser to see exactly what you're PHP is working with.

(Edit: what Jonathan said...)